# Unsafe cast of protocol to struct

Tags: swift, casting, swift-protocols

I want to know if there is a way to cast a protocol to a struct without checking if the underlying value is actually that struct.

My reason for asking is that using `as!` seems to have a big performance hit. So for example:

```swift
let val: MyProtocol = MyStruct()
let val2: MyStruct = val as! MyStruct
```

I tried using `unsafeBitCast` to cast `val` to `val2`

```swift
let val2: MyStruct = unsafeBitCast(val, to: MyStruct.self)
```

but this gave me a

```bash
Fatal error: Can't unsafeBitCast between types of different sizes
zsh: illegal hardware instruction
```

Is there any way to accomplish unsafe (or at least faster) casting using protocols?

Comment: You can add method to protocol `castToMyStruct`

Comment: @Cy-4AH but then the protocol is strongly coupled to the struct which is a bit odd and any other type that conforms to the protocol would need to implement that function

Comment: Isn't you will receive the crash when perform `as! MyStruct ` for any other type?